# Can You "Turn Off" Order of Preference For Wi-Fi Networks

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, preferences

As far as my MacBook is concerned, I have 3 Wi-Fi Networks in my house, with different names (it is actually one network, with 2 repeaters). I move around the house and frequently use the 2 repeaters in particular. Quite often I lose connection to one of the repeaters, and my laptop will reconnect, but possibly to the farther repeater with a weaker signal, depending on the order of preference set in advanced network preferences. Because this signal may be quite weak, I may lose Internet connection using this Wi-Fi repeater, but my laptop will not try to connect to the repeater with the stronger signal.

The only way to get round this is to continually change my network preferences whenever I move around the house, which is very annoying.

Is there any way I can get my laptop to have no preference between the two repeaters, and to connect to which ever has the stronger signal?

This is not a duplicate question because the other question is asking how to *enable* an order of preference on an iphone and this question is asking how to *disable* it on a Macbook. Not surprisingly, none of the answers there answer my question.

Comment: there are some good answers here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53703/46541

Comment: @Buscar I couldn't see anything there that would help me here. If you think otherwise could you be more specific? Regardless the question is not a duplicate because it is asking essentially the opposite thing for a different class of device.

Comment: You can not "turn off the order" it is a list and something always has to be in the first place. And I read your question as accessing multiple AP's on same network, that was answered by http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53704/46541. The device type has nothing to do with it. Using the described method, the list of networks would be irrelevant (all the same SSID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without special functionality on the accesspoints themselves.

The thing you are referring to is called wireless roaming, something that usually can't be done with simple consumer hardware.

As for OS X, it only reconnects when the current connection is lost. If you can make sure there is no overlap between the accesspoints or repeatets, the connection will always be lost and then you will switch to the next network. This might be possible in your situation if your repeaters or accesspoints allow you to reduce it's radio power in it's settings.

Comment: My movements are too fluid for reducing power to be a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Reducing power won't make things go bad, but just reduces the overlap between the two radio modules. Right now you're not disconnect-roaming because you're not fulling disconnecting from the AP/Repeater. The only way to do that is to make sure both repeaters/AP's aren't in range of each other. It does require them to be wired up to your main router...