# How does one get iPhone to recognize wifi network of choice, as first choice?

Tags: iphone, wifi

I am working in an office that has its own wifi network...but there are also cable company hotspots around. Every time I come in the office, leave the office, come back to the office...my phone goes on Optimum hotspot. I want it to choose the local office wifi network. I would like to prioritize my iPhone wifi networks, not just "forget" one network.

I have adjusted this for my macbook but not sure how to do it for the iPhone. Probably an easy answer but i do not know it so I appreciate any help. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

If you have iCloud Keychain enabled, the prioritized list of networks from your Mac will sync to your phone, including the order.

If you don't want to enable it, though, I do not know of any way to arrange networks on the phone by priority, except by forgetting them all and adding them in order of desire (the ones added earlier in the process will be preferred.)

Comment: I do have Keychain on but this has not seemed to make a difference. Maybe I will just forget that network and see what happens. Perhaps forgetting it and then adding - after the others - will make a difference in priority. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use iCloud keychain like Hawken Mentioned, here's the [Apple KB Article on iOS WiFi priority](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202831)

You can also control it with an iOS config profile via the Apple Configurator - see some of the answers on [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53703/how-can-i-set-the-priority-of-wi-fi-networks-on-my-ios-device)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "forget this network" on the ones you aren't interested in, leaving just the office wifi.

Comment: Thanks for responding...but not exactly what I am looking for. I do not want to forget the network...I want to prioritize the order of the networks. I will still use the other network, just not in this location, therefore I do not want it to be forgotten.